# Let $f(x) = x^2$, and define $\alpha$ as follows, find $100\int_{-1}^{100}f\ d\alpha$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

Making edits to this question. I think I may have figured out how to do the first part of the question

[image]

Based on this website ([http://www.stat.rice.edu/~dobelman/notes_papers/math/Riemann.Stiltjes.pdf](http://www.stat.rice.edu/%7Edobelman/notes_papers/math/Riemann.Stiltjes.pdf)) Using a combination of the different ways of solving the problem. I was able to get the right answer. I think I solved/reasoned for the answer correctly.

$\int_{-1}^{100} f(x)d\alpha(x)= x^2(\alpha(2+)- x^2(\alpha(2-) + x^2(\alpha(3+)- x^2(\alpha(3-) = x^2(\frac 23 x -1 - 0) + x^2(1-\frac 23 x -1 - 0)$

$\int_{-1}^{100} f(x)d\alpha(x)= \int_{-1}^{100}x^2d\alpha=f(100)\alpha(100)-f(-1)\alpha(-1)-\int_{-1}^{100} \alpha(n)2xdx$

$f(100)=100^2$

$\alpha(100)=1$

$f(-1)=(-1)^2$

$\alpha(-1)=0$

$(100)^2-0-\int_{-1}^{100} \alpha(n)2xdx$

$(100)^2-\int_{2}^{3} (\frac 23 x -1)*2x dx - \int_{3}^{100} \alpha(100)2x dx$

$\alpha(100)=1$

$(100)^2-\int_{2}^{3} (\frac 23 x -1)*2x dx - \int_{3}^{100} 2x dx$

Solving the integral with the limits gives the answer $\frac {50}{9}$

[image]

Still need help with the second part of the question. Since f is not given, would you just disregard it? I mean just use the give \alpha to solve the problem?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: [Please don't repost like this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4324982/104041) You have already been introduced to MathJax.

Comment: @Shaun - I couldn't edit it on the other one so I deleted it and tried to resubmit it but somehow still did it incorrect. Sorry

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "alpha has constants rather than functions." I suspect you may be thinking about the $0$ and $1$ in the definition of $\alpha(x)$, but I don't see why those constants should cause a problem. After all, a function can perfectly well be constant on part (or even all) of its domain.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I understand that a function can be a constant on parts of a domain but I'm not sure on how to set up the problem because it's constant on part of the domain. In the example problem, in the link, each worked out problem has either a function associated with it or a constant value. And my homework problem is different from those. Which is making me unsure on the setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\alpha$ is constant, the Stieljes integral is $0$. Suppose $\alpha(x) = m$ everywhere on $[c,d]$. If $P=(\{x_i\}_{i=0}^n, \{t_i\}_{i=1}^n)$ is a partition of $[c,d]$, then the Riemann-Stieljes sum over $P$ for $\int_c^d f\,d\alpha$ is
$$S(P,f) = \sum_{k=1}^n f(t_k)(\alpha(x_k) - \alpha(x_{k-1}))$$
But since $\alpha$ is constant, $\alpha(x_k) - \alpha(x_{k-1}) = 0$ for every $k$,so $S(P,f) = 0$, regardless of the partition $P$ or integrand $f$. Thus every function $f$ is integrable with respect to $\alpha$, and
$$\int_c^d f(x)\,d\alpha(x) = 0$$

So in the case of your first problem,

$$\begin{align}\int_{-1}^{100}f(x)\,d\alpha(x) &= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0+}\int_{-1}^{2-\epsilon}f(x)\,d\alpha(x) + \int_{2-\epsilon}^{3}f(x)\,d\alpha(x) + \int_{3}^{100}f(x)\,d\alpha(x)\\
&= 0 + \int_{2-}^{3}f(x)\,d\alpha(x) + 0\end{align}$$
Where the $2-$ indicates that you still have to account for the discontinuity of $\alpha$ at $2$ within the remaining integral.

In the second problem, they are asking you to calculate
$$\int_0^n x\,d\alpha(x)$$
The function that needs to be integrated is whatever is between the $\int$ and the $d\alpha(x)$ (as used here - there is another notational convention where the integrand is given after the $d\alpha(x)$ and you have to guess what is included in it and what is not). The integrand does not have to named "$f$". And the function with respect to which you are integrating  does not have to named "$\alpha$", though they still did so here.

So you integrate the function $x$ with respect to the function $\lfloor x \rfloor$.